# Oracle - Why is the dummy column in DUAL type varchar2(1) and not an integer?

Tags: database, oracle

SELECT * FROM dual;

This table has 1 column called Dummy of type varchar2(1)
Anyone who knows why the column is varchar2 and not an integer?

Comment: Why should it be `integer` and not `varchar2(1)`?

Comment: What's wrong with it being a `varchar`?

Comment: Off the top of my head, because 'X' (the default value) isn't a number. As to why the table was created as it was, you'd have to ask it's creator, Chuck Weiss.

Comment: Of course, if the database is closed then a query against dual returns four columns, not one ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's just convenience table. Do you really use DUMMY column that much?

```
SELECT 1 DUMMY FROM DUAL
```

And you have integer.

Btw. if you ask why the name 'DUAL'? Back in the days it had two rows.